# do not receive parameter

Tags: javascript, java, spring, html

**JSP**

```
<form action="test.do" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude">
   <input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude">
   <input type="hidden" value="send">
</form>
```

**Console.log output :**

```
console.log('latitude:'  , latitude)
 > <input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude">12.345678</input>
 < undefined
```

[image]

```
console.log('longitude: ' ,  longitude)
```

**Spring ViewController**

```
@RequestMapping("test.do")
public ModelAndView getLoction(String latitude, String longitude, HttpServletRequest rq){

latitude = rq.getParameter("latitude");
longitude = rq.getParameter("longitude");

System.out.println("latitude : " + latitude);
System.out.println("longitude : " + longitude);
```

**result output**

```
latitude : null
longitude : null
```

Comment: I don't see submit button in your form.So I doubt you are submitting the form and that your method is called on the get request (the initial rendering) of the page and with that nothing exists.

Comment: you should check your code carefully again, your `@RequestMapping` says `GET`, your form says `POST`

Comment: Dear M. Deinum
thanks for your help. 
I want the code without the button and than 
I have already received the data from the jsp.
I just do not get a value from the Spring Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should submit the form.

Change your JSP to

```
<form action="test.do" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude">
 <input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude">
 <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

In your Spring Controller you don't need to use HttpServletRequest. Spring use auto binding for these properties.

```
@RequestMapping("test.do")
public ModelAndView getLoction(String latitude, String longitude){

 System.out.println("latitude : " + latitude);
 System.out.println("longitude : " + longitude);
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike Adamenko,
yes i do, i don't need HttpServletRequest, but i don't receive latitude and longitude to Spring Controller.
$(function(){
 if(navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
   $('#latitude').html(pos.coords.latitude);
   $('#longitude').html(pos.coords.longitude);
  });
 }else{
  alert("do not support Geolocation")
 }
 });